# Numpy vs regular array in python

Tags: python

This might be a beginner question but

when I run this code

```
[[0.] for i in range(num_features)]
```

I get `[[0.],[0.]]`

When I run this code

```
np.zeros((2, 1))
```

I get

```
[[0.],

 [0.]]
```

As in two separate lines

Is there a significant difference between the two? If so, what's the right way to write the first bit of code?

Comment: One is a list and the other is a numpy array.

Comment: Check this out -> https://webcourses.ucf.edu/courses/1249560/pages/python-lists-vs-numpy-arrays-what-is-the-difference

Comment: makes sense. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

First list is a regular list comprehension, second is a numpy array, it is **TOTALLY** different, here is the numpy documentation:

http://www.numpy.org/

So actually second one could be a list like the first one:

```
>>> np.zeros((2, 1)).tolist()
[[0.0], [0.0]]
>>>
```